# Hibernate: [Entity] is not mapped

Tags: hibernate, kotlin

I have configured Hibernate in a Kotlin-vertx project, I managed to set up everything but when I run a HQL query it ouputs:

> SEVERE: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Movie is
>   not mapped [SELECT m FROM Movie AS m WHERE m.id=:id]
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Movie is not
>   mapped [SELECT m FROM Movie AS m WHERE m.id=:id]  at
>   org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:138)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:181)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:188)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:729)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:745)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:23)
>     at MonoServer$main$4.handle(MonoServer.kt:46)   at
>   MonoServer$main$4.handle(MonoServer.kt:14)    at
>   io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RouteImpl.handleContext(RouteImpl.java:231)     at
>   io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RoutingContextImplBase.iterateNext(RoutingContextImplBase.java:121)
>     at
>   io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RoutingContextImpl.next(RoutingContextImpl.java:131)
>     at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RouterImpl.handle(RouterImpl.java:80)  at
>   io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RouterImpl.handle(RouterImpl.java:41)   at
>   io.vertx.ext.web.Router.accept(Router.java:64)    at
>   MonoServer$main$3.handle(MonoServer.kt:39)    at
>   MonoServer$main$3.handle(MonoServer.kt:14)    at
>   io.vertx.core.http.impl.WebSocketRequestHandler.handle(WebSocketRequestHandler.java:50)
>     at
>   io.vertx.core.http.impl.WebSocketRequestHandler.handle(WebSocketRequestHandler.java:32)
>     at
>   io.vertx.core.http.impl.HttpServerRequestImpl.handleBegin(HttpServerRequestImpl.java:149)
>     at
>   io.vertx.core.http.impl.Http1xServerConnection.handleMessage(Http1xServerConnection.java:135)
>     at io.vertx.core.impl.ContextImpl.executeTask(ContextImpl.java:369)
>     at
>   io.vertx.core.impl.EventLoopContext.execute(EventLoopContext.java:43)
>     at io.vertx.core.impl.ContextImpl.executeFromIO(ContextImpl.java:232)
>     at
>   io.vertx.core.net.impl.VertxHandler.channelRead(VertxHandler.java:173)
>     at
>   io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:359)
>     at
>   io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:345)
>     at
>   io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:337)
>     at
>   io.vertx.core.http.impl.Http1xUpgradeToH2CHandler.channelRead(Http1xUpgradeToH2CHandler.java:99)
>     at
>   io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:359)
>     at
>   io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:345)
>     at
>   io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:337)
>     at
>   io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:323)
>     at
>   io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:297)
>     at
>   io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:359)
>     at
>   io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:345)
>     at
>   io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:337)
>     at
>   io.vertx.core.http.impl.Http1xOrH2CHandler.end(Http1xOrH2CHandler.java:61)
>     at
>   io.vertx.core.http.impl.Http1xOrH2CHandler.channelRead(Http1xOrH2CHandler.java:38)
>     at
>   io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:359)
>     at
>   io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:345)
>     at
>   io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:337)
>     at
>   io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1408)
>     at
>   io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:359)
>     at
>   io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:345)
>     at
>   io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:930)
>     at
>   io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:163)
>     at
>   io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:677)
>     at
>   io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:612)
>     at
>   io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:529)
>     at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:491)     at
>   io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:905)
>     at
>   io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
>     at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) Caused by:
>   org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Movie is not
>   mapped [SELECT m FROM Movie AS m WHERE m.id=:id]  at
>   org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException.generateQueryException(QuerySyntaxException.java:79)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.QueryException.wrapWithQueryString(QueryException.java:103)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:220)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:144)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.(HQLQueryPlan.java:113)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.(HQLQueryPlan.java:73)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:158)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.getQueryPlan(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:611)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:720)
>     ... 49 more Caused by:
>   org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Movie is not
>   mapped    at
>   org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.util.SessionFactoryHelper.requireClassPersister(SessionFactoryHelper.java:169)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromElementFactory.addFromElement(FromElementFactory.java:91)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromClause.addFromElement(FromClause.java:79)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.HqlSqlWalker.createFromElement(HqlSqlWalker.java:331)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromElement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:3695)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromElementList(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:3584)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromClause(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:720)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.query(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:576)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectStatement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:313)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.statement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:261)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.analyze(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:272)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:192)
>     ... 55 more

My persistence.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="2.1" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="default">
        <description>Persistence XML</description>
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
        <properties>

            <!-- Hibernate Config -->
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect" />
            <property name="hibernate.generate_statistics" value="false" />
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
            <property name="hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy" value="org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.charSet" value="UTF-8"/>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="false"/>
            <property name="hibernate.use_sql_comments" value="false"/>

            <!-- JDBC Config -->
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/monolith_db" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="monolith_user" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="monolith_user_pwd" />

        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

I am invoking the query like this:

```
val query = em.createQuery("SELECT m FROM Movie AS m WHERE m.id=:id", Movie::class.java)
                query.setParameter("id", 2)
                val movie = query.singleResult
```

My entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "movie")
class Movie(
    var title: String = "",
    var summary: String = ""
) : StandardEntity() {

    override fun toString(): String {
        return "Movie[id=$id, title=$title, summary=${summary.substring(0, 30)}"
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you pls check whether you have annotated your class with `@org.hibernate.annotations.Entity` instead of `@javax.persistence.Entity`? See your `import` declarations in the `Movie` class.

Comment: Yes I had javax.persistence.Entity @MWiesner, I tried with org.hibernate.annotations.Entity but it didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar issue and came to this question multiple times, for your error
it looks like it's related with the configuration of your JPA provider, try to configure it with spring instead and see if it helps

I'm assuming that's the root cause since in other post it was telling me that Intellij was not able to map the entity because JPA provider wasn't configured, so once I fixed my mapping as described below, it stopped failing

In my case it was something more stupid because I was using `@Entity(name = "nameOfTheTable")`, when it should be `@Entity(name = "nameOfEntity"), @Table(name = "nameOfTable")`

Also give it a try to the next and see if it helps. Try to add a custom name to your entity in @Entity and use that name, I.E:

```
@Entity(name = "MyMovieEntity")
@Table(name = "movie")
```

And then try to use it in your query:

```
val query = em.createQuery("SELECT m FROM MyMovieEntity AS m WHERE m.id=:id", Movie::class.java)
                query.setParameter("id", 2)
                val movie = query.singleResult
```